# Retrieving instance from array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, instance

I have a `scoreboard` that has many `games`. `game` has_many `users` and `user` has_many `games`, so I have a join table/model `game_users`.
`Scoreboard` belongs_to `competition`. My admin can generate a scoreboard linked to a competition.
The idea is to generate the scoreboard and (`@competition.users.count / 2`) games on that scoreboard (provided we have a even number of players). A game is a confrontation between 2 players.

In my scoreboard_controller, I have :

```
 def create
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.new
    @scoreboard.competition = @competition
    authorize @scoreboard

    if @scoreboard.save
      if @competition.users && @competition.users.count.even?
        @total_players = @competition.users
        num = 0
        for num in 0..(@competition.users.count / 2) do
          game = Game.new(scoreboard: @scoreboard)
          game.save
          gameUserFirst = GameUser.new(game: game, user: @total_players.sample)
          @total_players = @total_players.except(gameUserFirst.user)
          gameUserSecond = GameUser.new(game: game, user: @total_players.sample)
          @total_players = @total_players.except(gameUserSecond.user)
          gameUserFirst.save
          gameUserSecond.save
          num += 1
        end
      end
      redirect_to  competition_scoreboard_path(@competition, @scoreboard)
    else
    end
  end
```

My goal is to generate games between random players, but I dont want a player to be selected twice or to play against himself. In order to prevent this, as soon as it is used in the  `GameUser` object, I want to retrieve it from the  `@total_players` array. 
Unfortunately the `.except` method doesn't seem to work with instances. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-=` instead of `except`:

```
@total_players -= [gameUserFirst.user]
```

But I would suggest another approach to create the matches: You can make an array of all user ids, shuffle it, and then pick combos:

```
@competition.user_ids.shuffle.in_groups_of(2).each do |user_id_1, user_id_2|
  # Create game...
end
```

Another point: Having that much business logic in your controller is often not a good thing. Could be placed in an `after_create` method in the `Scoreboard` model.